# How do I create a bivariate map legend (3x3 cells) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I would like to create a bivariate map, and need to create a 2 dimensional legend to accompany it.  How do I create a bivariate map legend (3x3 cells) in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [great resource about bivariate maps in QGIS](http://www.joshuastevens.net/cartography/make-a-bivariate-choropleth-map/), and it includes info about creating a legend.

EDIT: You will create the legend outside of QGIS, and bring it in to the layout (whether you do the layout in QGIS Composer or another graphics program).